# Commutator for field with its adjoint

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

Is it possible to derive the commutator relationship $[\phi^{\dagger}(x),\phi(y)]=0$ from $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. I assume, you are considering the Schrödinger field with $\pi=i\phi^*$ or $\widehat\pi=i\widehat\phi^\dagger$ after canonical quantization, then notice that the commutators:
$$[\widehat\phi(t,x),\widehat\phi(t,y)]
=[\widehat\pi(t,x),\widehat\pi(t,y)]=0$$
do not depend on $x$ or $y$, while the commutator:
$$[\widehat\phi(t,x),\widehat\pi(t,y)]=i\hbar\delta^3(x-y)$$
does. Therefore there can't be a derivation of the lower equation using the upper equations.

Comment: I‘m actually referring to a complex free scalar field but there the commutators should be also independent.

Comment: Yes, it's the same argument and irrelevant of what quantum field you are using. The Schrödinger field was just a guess as $\widehat\phi^\dagger$ appears in your commutator. For the Dirac field, you'd also have $\widehat\pi=i\widehat\psi^\dagger$ for example. What you can indeed do in both of these cases though is derive the commutator $[\widehat\pi(t,x),\widehat\pi(t,y)]=0$ from the commutator $[\widehat\phi(t,x),\widehat\phi(t,y)]$ (or vice versa), by just applying $\cdot^\dagger$, so you really don't need all three.